# Is it possible to show __init_subclass__ docstring on the subclass?

Tags: python, python-3.x, docstring

Let's say I have a class that implement __init_subclass__ with two parameters:

```
class Foo:

    def __init_subclass__(name: str, surname: str):
        """
        name: The name of the user
        surname: The surname of the user
        """
        ...
```

When I subclass from Foo. I would like to be able to see in the docstring of the subclassed class the description of the two parameter (name, surname). Is there any way to achieve this ?
This way when a user subclass from Foo, he knows what to put in the parameters of the class

```
class Bar(Foo, name = 'bar', surname = 'xxx')
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure, I understand you correctly, but to add the docs of `__init_subclass__` to the subclasses of `Foo` you can update subclasses `__doc__`:

```
class Foo:
    def __init_subclass__(cls, name: str, surname: str, **kwargs):
        """
        name: The name of the user
        surname: The surname of the user
        """
        cls.__doc__ = Foo.__init_subclass__.__doc__ + cls.__doc__


class Bar(Foo, name='bar', surname='xxx'):
    """Docs of Bar"""
```

Then

```
>>> print(Bar.__doc__)

        name: The name of the user
        surname: The surname of the user
        Docs of Bar
```

Comment: Thanks that is one way to do it! I don't know why the VsCode Intelissence is not showing it though. I guess it's because __init_subclass__ is only processed later on, when the code is executed